# separate column with unknown name

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a data frame like this:

```
structure(list(header = 1:10, ST.adk.fumC.gyrB.icd.mdh.purA.recA = c(" 10 10 11 4 8 8 8 2", 
" 48 6 11 4 8 8 8 2", " 58 6 4 4 16 24 8 14", " 88* 6* 4 12 1 20 12 7", 
" 117 20 45 41 43 5 32 2", " 7036 526 7 1 1 8 71 6", " 101 43 41 15 18 11 7 6", 
" 3595 112 11 5 12 8 88 86", " 117 20 45 41 43 5 32 2", " 744 10 11 135 8 8 8 2"
)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

What I want to do is to split the second column into separate columns, separated by the "." in the column name. However, it's not always known what the name of the column is, which is why I cannot use the name of the column in dplyr' "separate" function.

I tried the following:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)

# get new column names
ids <- unlist(strsplit(names(df)[-1],
                              split = ".",
                              fixed = TRUE))

# get name of column to split
split_column <- names(df)[-1]

df %>%
separate(split_column, into = ids, extra = "merge")
```

This works within the script file I am using, but when i source the script I get the following error:

```
Error: `var` must evaluate to a single number or a column name, not a character vector
```

Why does this work when I run it like normal in RStudio, but when I source the script it throws this error?
Also, is this the optimal way of actually splitting a column of unknown name into new columns with unknown names?

I source the script with the following code, in another script file:

```
system(paste("Rscript script.R", opt$m, opt$o))
```

Where opt$m and opt$o are directory paths. This works fine with a similar script I have, but with the script above it throws an error.

I was hoping for some kind of function like separate_at, but that doesn't exist as of yet..

Comment: Works fine for me: R version 3.4.2, tidyr_0.8.1 dplyr_0.7.7

Comment: You might have different versions of R or packages, when using Rstudio vs using sourcing the script.

Comment: @zx8754 yes I think that must be the case - I will check out the versions

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Two things: you might want to run your split column through trimws() before separating, otherwise your first column will be blank with the data you gave. Second - consider calling `tidyr::separate()`, as your script maybe accessing a different package for some reason.

Comment: (also, separate is from `tidyr`, not `dplyr`)

Comment: x[-1]  means drop the first element.  That is, it will be the list of  all of the others.  You want `names(df)[2]` to get just the name you want.

Comment: Or, instead of what @Elin suggested, you can just give separate the number of the column you want to split - 2 in this case - and not care what the actual name of it is.

Comment: @iod If I use only the number 2, I get the following error:
Error: `var` must be a value between 0 and 0 (excluding zero), not 2. This is why I thought to use the name instead

Comment: yeah, there's probably a problem with your R version/packages. That error is bizarre

Comment: I updated the question with the source part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `strsplit()`.

```
split <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(gsub("\\*", "", df[, -1]), " "))[, -1]
df1 <- data.frame(df[, 1], split)
df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
names(df1) <- unlist(strsplit(names(df), split = ".", fixed=TRUE))

> df1
   header   ST adk fumC gyrB icd mdh purA recA
1       1   10  10   11    4   8   8    8    2
2       2   48   6   11    4   8   8    8    2
3       3   58   6    4    4  16  24    8   14
4       4   88   6    4   12   1  20   12    7
5       5  117  20   45   41  43   5   32    2
6       6 7036 526    7    1   1   8   71    6
7       7  101  43   41   15  18  11    7    6
8       8 3595 112   11    5  12   8   88   86
9       9  117  20   45   41  43   5   32    2
10     10  744  10   11  135   8   8    8    2
```

***Data***

```
df <-structure(list(header = 1:10, ST.adk.fumC.gyrB.icd.mdh.purA.recA = c(" 10 10 11 4 8 8 8 2", 
                                                                     " 48 6 11 4 8 8 8 2", " 58 6 4 4 16 24 8 14", " 88* 6* 4 12 1 20 12 7", 
                                                                     " 117 20 45 41 43 5 32 2", " 7036 526 7 1 1 8 71 6", " 101 43 41 15 18 11 7 6", 
                                                                     " 3595 112 11 5 12 8 88 86", " 117 20 45 41 43 5 32 2", " 744 10 11 135 8 8 8 2"
)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much the same solution as your example with a few tweaks. This is how I would do it, assuming you want to remove the `'*'` in the columns:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(hablar)

# Vector of new column names
ids <- simplify(strsplit(names(df)[-1], 
                         split = ".", 
                         fixed = T))

# Seperate second column
df %>%
  mutate_at(2, funs(trimws(gsub("\\*", "", .)))) %>%
  separate(2, into = ids, extra = "merge", sep = " ") %>% 
  retype()
```

gives you:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 9
   header    ST   adk  fumC  gyrB   icd   mdh  purA  recA
    <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1      1    10    10    11     4     8     8     8     2
 2      2    48     6    11     4     8     8     8     2
 3      3    58     6     4     4    16    24     8    14
 4      4    88     6     4    12     1    20    12     7
 5      5   117    20    45    41    43     5    32     2
 6      6  7036   526     7     1     1     8    71     6
 7      7   101    43    41    15    18    11     7     6
 8      8  3595   112    11     5    12     8    88    86
 9      9   117    20    45    41    43     5    32     2
10     10   744    10    11   135     8     8     8     2
```